# Java: Array Average calculator - Read & Write to and from textfile

Tags: java, arrays

**my instructions go as followed:** "Write a Java program that prompts the user to enter 10 integers.  The program must then save the 10 integers into a text file called numbers.txt.  The program must then read back in the 10 numbers from the file and display the average of the numbers.  HINT: you should save the integers as strings and then convert them back into Integers after reading them back in from the file.  Your program must utilize proper exception handling for the case that there is an error writing or reading the file.  Also your program needs to include proper javadoc comments."
UPDATE: sorry for not being specific i was rushing to work, I'm having problem conceptualizing how my write and read to file should look. i think most of my code is right. i just need help calling read file to show average and help placing how my write to file should look

excuse the slop i was gonna tidy it up a bit i currently have:

```
package average;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class average {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);  
        String prompt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 10 numbers to average ");


        switch(prompt) {

        case "read": openFileRead(); readFromFile(); closeFileRead();
        break;
        case "write": openFileWrite(); writeToFile(); closeFile();
        break;
        default: System.out.println("Input not recognized.");


}

}
    public static void openFileRead() {      // gets file for "read"
        try {
            input = new Scanner(Paths.get("Numbers.txt"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read file");
        }
    }

    public static void openFileWrite() {     // gets file for "write"
        try {
            output = new Formatter("Numbers.txt");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file");
        }

    }

    public static void readFromFile() {   
        System.out.print(average);

    }

      public static void writeToFile() {  
          Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
          int num[] = new int[10];
          int average = 0;
          int i = 0;
          int sum = 0;

          for (i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
              System.out.println("enter a number");
              num[i] = input.nextInt();
              sum=sum+num[i];
          }
          average=sum/10;
          System.out.println("Average="+average);
          }
    //required to close file for write
        public static void closeFile() {
            output.close();
        }

        //required to close file for read
        public static void closeFileRead() {
            input.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You need to describe what your problem is with your code, does it crash or return the wrong result or... We can't help you if you don't tell us what you need help with.

Comment: i apologize i was rushing i updated my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<num.length; i++) 
{
   System.out.println("enter a number");
   num[i] = input.nextInt();
   sum += num[i];
}
```